# корректная ссылка звонка с сайта

Tags: html

Вообщем проблема такая
Установил ссылку для звонка с сайта
Вот так работает:

```
<a id="cell" href="tel:+7(777)777-77-77"><img src="img/phone.png"></ a>
```

А вот так нет:

```
<a id="cell" href="tel:+7(351)777-38-07"><img src="img/phone.png"></a>
```

Разница в разрыве закрывающего тега

Что не так? Ведь по идее второй вариант должен работать?

Comment: второй вариант конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работать должен второй вариант. Пробела в закрывающем теге ссылки не должно быть. Скорее всего, вы использовали пример с сайта html5.by. Там опечатка.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, проблема была в css